# Javascript Parent and Children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had a problem using a function inside another function, and it still don't work with parent and children that people told me.

Have you got any idea ?

```
this.suiv.click(function () {
    this.div.parent.children(".crea").each(function () {
        //self.index=parseInt($(this).css("z-index"));
        alert("wesh2");
    }
});
```

Edit : 
Here are some more details on what actually happen when I use my page.
The click on "suiv" work fine, but the problem seems to come from the second function "crea". Even when I use "parentElement" or "parent" or "_this" the alert doesn't pop up.

Edit 2:
Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="galerie">
        <div class="slider">

        <div class="crea" style="z-index: 9"><img src="img.jpg"></div>
        <div class="crea" style="z-index: 8"><img src="img.jpg"></div>
        <div class="crea" style="z-index: 7"><img src="img.jpg"></div>
        <div class="crea" style="z-index: 6"><img src="img.jpg"></div>
        <div class="crea" style="z-index: 5"><img src="img.jpg"></div>
        <div class="crea" style="z-index: 4"><img src="img.jpg"></div>
        <div class="crea" style="z-index: 3" ><img src="img.jpg"></div>
        <div class="crea" style="z-index: 2"><img src="img.jpg"></div>
        <div class="crea" style="z-index: 1"><img src="img.jpg"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="suiv"></div>
        <div class="prec"></div>

     </div>
```

And here is my complete script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
s = new slider(".galerie");
});

var slider = function(id){
    var self=this;
    this.div = $(id);
    this.nb=0;
    this.index=0;


        this.div.find(".crea").each(function(){


            self.nb++;
                    //alert($(this).css("z-index"));


        });
    alert(this.nb);
        this.index = 0;
        this.suiv = this.div.find(".suiv");
        this.prec = this.div.find(".prec");

        _this=this
        this.suiv.click(function () {
            _this.div.parent().children(".crea").each(function () {
                //self.index=parseInt($(this).css("z-index"));
                alert("wesh2");
            });
        });



}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To help you answer your question, could you describe in more detail what is the problem you are having? Are you getting any errors in your console? Have you tried debugging your problem with breakpoints? These things will surely help.

Comment: I don't think `parent` is a property of an HTML DOM element. `parentNode` and `parentElement` then again are. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Comment: can you post your `HTML` structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `parentElement` instead of `parent` in your selector

Comment: or it might be parentNode

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error.

```
this.suiv.click(function () {
    this.div.parent.children(".crea").each(function () {
        //self.index=parseInt($(this).css("z-index"));
        alert("wesh2");
    });
//   ^      
});
```

Comment: Indeed, however when i click my div, the alert message don't appear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to change images when press "suiv" or "prec"

why not something like this

```
$('.suiv').on("click").function(){ 
  $('.crea').each(function () {

        $(this).html(itemarrayofimages);

    });
});
```

Comment: I would like to change the "z-index" mainly, not the image, it would be more easy for me.

Comment: is the approaach that is wrong, for me. why to catch parent and its childrens when you have the entire set of element in a single shoot. change the prop("style","z-index: x"). sorry if i am misunderstanding your need

Comment: As you can see on my HTML i have differents imgs that are superimposed and my goal is to increase the z-index (++) for each img except for the last one (which will come back to 1) so it will show an other img etc...

Answer (score -1):

yes, your problem here is that "this" is overwritten so this.div.parent is wrong

try this:

```
_this=this
this.suiv.click(function () {
    _this.div.parent().children(".crea").each(function () {
        //self.index=parseInt($(this).css("z-index"));
        alert("wesh2");
    });
});
```

So when you said this.div.parent you were referring to "this" as the object that has  a property that you called div.    But within a click handler, this will refer to the actual element.  So I think what people may have been telling you to do is

```
this.parent.children(
```

not

```
this.div.parent.children(
```

because this in the handler will be the object clicked on, so it's parent would be the one containing the other siblings you want to work with.

Javascript's `this` is confusing when doing "classes".  So you write:

```
var myclass=function(){
    this.abc="hi"

    this.doStuff=function(){
        _this=this;  // "this" is still myClass

        //but this will be overwritten in a jquery event handler
        //so you'll want to store "this" for use in event handlers
        $('div').click(function(){console.log(this, _this)});
    }

};
```

Comment: whoever downvoted me does not know what they're talking about.  I don't care, but I want the OP to see his problem.  I actually saw the other problem he posted.

Comment: Thank you Awoke. Where should I write the last function you gave me ?

Comment: @Ezhno the "last" function is just an example of how "this" gets overwritten within the click handler.  you should actually use the first part I wrote at the top of the answer.  that includes _this=this for keeping the reference to the object that contains "div" (this.div)

Comment: @Ezhno if you already tried it, I forgot the parenthesis after parent()  I edited the response just now.